# Opening Catia from Microsoft Access VBA results in ENOIEF3DExpServices.dll not found

Tags: vba, ms-access, catia

One of the features of a MS Access DB I created is to open each of our Catia versions (R27, R28, R30) directly, using VBA (by default we have 3 versions of Catia on our desktop all with the same icons and similar titles).
They all open just fine and have no issues except for one of the revisions (R27, the oldest - rev 2017) won't let you connect to 3Dexperience - when you try, it displays an error saying C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B421xcadconnectors\win_b64\code\bin\ENOIEF3DExpServices.dll: Can't find dependent libraries: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcOlX.png)
**However, I have searched and that library is there. Maybe it can't find a library that the mentioned .dll relies on? Is there a way to find what libraries it relies on?**

Once this error occurs, the only way to fix it is to completed kill your session (we use VMware) and grab a brand new one (shut down and restart completely)

This error only happens when you open from the database.

What's weird is that Catia R27 has always done this (about a year since we created this MS Access DB) but Catia R30 JUST started doing this last week.
Our workaround is having VBA open a folder with only the relevant Catia shortcut in it. Not the worst, but would like to open it directly so users don't have to manually close yet another explorer window.

I have tried many different methods of opening from VBA - all calling on the desktop shortcut directly.

1. ShellExecute 0, "OPEN", "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\CATIA V5-6R2017.lnk", "", "", 1
2. CreateObject("Shell.Application").open CVar("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\CATIA V5-6R2017.lnk")
3. Shell "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\CATIA V5-6R2017.lnk", vbnormalfocus

I am able to open Catia R27 via a batch file directly with no issues, but *even if I open the batch file that opens Catia R27 from MS Access, this error still occurs*
This is the command in the batch file:
start "" "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\CATIA V5-6R2017.lnk"

Comment: How are you going about registering the correct libraries when you switch versions? Does your launch script run CNEXT -regserver ? 
Opening R27 when R29 libraries are registered seems a likely way to get an error like this.

Comment: Here is what the target in the shortcut looks like:
"E:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B27-Toyota\win_b64\code\bin\CATSTART.exe" -run "CNEXT.exe" -env CATIA.V5-6R2017_TOYOTA.B27 -direnv "\\uem\uem\CATEnv" -nowindow

So it's referencing CNEXT.exe in the code\bin folder in the program data. The weird thing is that all this works perfectly when I manually open the shortcut to Catia R27 from my desktop. The issue is ONLY when I open the shortuct via VBA in MS Access